# Setting resource paths programatically in spring MVC

Tags: spring, resources

My MVC application will need access to thumbnails and video files outside the servlet context. So I have set up the servlet-context.xml to have the following:

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/,file:/home/john/temp_jpgs/" />
```

So the images inside /home/john/temp_jpgs/ are available to any jsp under /resources.

However, this is only for testing, and I would like to be able to set this location programatically. How do I do that?

Thanks,
John.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `<resources ...` tag doesn't do what you want, you could subclass [ResourceHttpRequestHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/ResourceHttpRequestHandler.html) to include whatever functionality you need.

**Example: Subclass ResourceHttpRequestHandler for custom Location**

```
package com.test;

public class MyCustomResourceHttpRequestHandler extends ResourceHttpRequestHandler {

    private String yourCustomPath;

    @Override
    protected Resource getResource(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String path = (String)  request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
...

       //put whatever logic you need in here
       return new FileSystemResource(yourCustomPath + path);

    }

    public void setYourCustomPath(String path){
        this.yourCustomPath = path;
    }
}
```

Now, you can drop your `<resources ...` tag and register your handlers in the context as below. Then, requests coming in for `/resources/**` would get routed to your custom class. You would basically be controlling the `location` by changing the `yourCustomPath` variable via setters.

```
<bean name="resourceHandler" class="com.test.MyCustomResourceHttpRequestHandler">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <!-- you'll be overriding this programmatically -->
            <value>/resources/</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="urlMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="/resources/**" value-ref="resourceHandler"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

You can now inject the `resourceHandler` bean into any other class, call a setter to set `yourCustomPath` and change it programmatically.

Comment: Thank you kevinpeterson. I am new to Spring, and so I need a little bit of help setting this solution up. How would I add a new path, and use this new class?

Comment: See updated answer - I've added a more concrete example. Please let me know if it is unclear.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort. Just what I needed.