# Spring AOP on ResourceHttpRequestHandler

Tags: java, spring-mvc, aop

I need resources mapping like `<mvc:resources mapping="/id1/resources/**" location="/id1/resources/static" />`, `<mvc:resources mapping="/id2/resources/**" location="/id2/resources/static" />` for each product(each of which can have its own static css, javascript...). Because the product will be created at run time, I cannot simply hard code each resource mapping declaration. So the approach I could think of is to use AOP to rewrite the resource location for each resource request.

First of all, I have the Aspect class

```
public class ResAudience {

    public void anyMethodBefore() {
        System.out.println("any method before ...");
    }

    public void anyMethodAfter() {
        System.out.println("any method return ...");
    }
}
```

I found the resource request is handled by  [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/ResourceHttpRequestHandler.html). So the AOP configuration

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="resAspect">
        <aop:pointcut id="resHandler" expression="execution(* org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler..*(..))" />
        <aop:before pointcut-ref="resHandler" method="anyMethodBefore"/>
        <aop:after pointcut-ref="resHandler" method="anyMethodAfter"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

I was holping to re-write the location via AOP based on the request such as [ResourceHttpRequestHandler#setLocations(List locations)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/ResourceHttpRequestHandler.html#setLocations-java.util.List-), but the only function being called during the application life cycle is [ResourceHttpRequestHandler#handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/ResourceHttpRequestHandler.html#handleRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-), where I don't seem to have chance to re-write the location.

I am sure there must be something I am missing. Would someone help find the way the re-write the location during the run-time(not necessary to use AOP)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Answer my own quesstion.

For my need, create resource mapping for static resources dynamically, this solution works for me, [Setting resource paths programatically in spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386383/setting-resource-paths-programatically-in-spring-mvc)